# Nested API calls in React.js

Tags: javascript, api, reactjs

I'm creating a web app in React that needs to handle 2 API calls where one is dependent on the other. The first API call will grab data from OpenWeather API - and then the 2nd API call will use that callback data to make a call to Spotify's API.

How can I set up this nested/dependent API call in React? Can I run an ajax call under the success function of the first API call? Or do I need to create a new component that handles the 2nd API, that will somehow get the data from the first API call?

```
    // Making the API call to OpenWeather API:
var CityInfo = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: {}};
    },
    loadCityInfo: function(e){
    var city = $(e.currentTarget).data('city');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                this.setState({data: result});
                console.log(result);

            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2><button onClick={this.loadCityInfo} data-city={this.props.info.name}>{this.props.info.name}</button></h2>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Full code: https://jsbin.com/lefupo/edit?js,output

Comment: *"Can I run an ajax call under the success function of the first API call?"* Of course. The `success` function is just another function. You can execute any other JavaScript in it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you follow flux pattern for making your requests especially.. however with what you have you can make a chained request

```
var CityInfo = React.createClass({
    loadCityInfo: function(e){
        var city = $(e.currentTarget).data('city');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+"&APPID=3c8e84ea9c6f7938384d3c3980033d80",
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(result) {
                this.setState({data: result});
                console.log(result);
                // make request here
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }
});
```

now that aside the way you can do this with flux pattern is have an actions file that does the requests..

```
module.exports = {
    loadWeather: function(city){
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='+city+"&APPID=3c8e84ea9c6f7938384d3c3980033d80",
            method: 'GET'
        });
    },
    loadSpotify: function(params){
        //do request here
    }
}
```

then in your loadcity function you can just do this

```
loadCityInfo: function(e){
    var city = $(e.currentTarget).data('city');
    actions.loadWeather(city).done(function(res){
        //set your state
        actions.loadSpotify(params)
    }).fail(funciton(res){
        //handle fail
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks again - I've come across Flux before but haven't fully grasped the syntax + setup yet. I ended up using your first example of creating a second function for the spotify api call - and then calling that function under the first success function..!

Comment: @YNINNY sure thing. the beautiful thing about flux is you can pass data from a child to any parent as well as any additional components that all listen to one store... aka the state is the stores values

Answer (score 1):

> Can I run an ajax call under the success function of the first API call?

Of course. The `success` function is just another function. You can execute any other JavaScript in it.

However, it would be cleaner to utilize the fact the [**`$.ajax`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a promise. So you could write this instead:

```
getWeatherData(city) // contains the Ajax call to OpenWeather
.then(getSpotifyData) // contains call to Spotify, gets passed result from getWeatherData
.then(function(result) {
  // update state
});
```

See [Deferreds](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/) for more info.